# Apply for a cluster for scientific computing from a developing country?

Tags: hpc

I don't have access to a computer cluster in my university. Is there website that accepts applications for free access to a computer cluster for scientific computing?

Further information: I am in Cuba. I need something on the order of 30 processors, about 50 GB of hard drive, for a week or so. I need to run programs written in C++ and Python.

Comment: I see. This is actually a very modest size -- some workstations have more than that. Clearly, you won't get this in the US because of the sanctions, but I would expect that some central or south American countries have resources many times larger and you may be able to get it done there. I'd just contact a couple of parallel computing researchers there.

Comment: Maybe you can make a request to a South American university. For instance: http://www.nlhpc.cl

Answer (score 1):

For access to machines in the US, your best bet is to work with a colleague at a US institution. NSF's XSEDE machines accept users from all over the world (persons physically in Iran, Cuba, Syria, Sudan, and North Korea, excepted for sure), but Principal Investigators for allocations must be at a US institution.

Comment: What about Iran, Cuba, Syria, ...? What options are available for them?

Comment: @becko, I don't have any information about use of systems outside the US. I would look at systems in the EU, India, and China. Though, my understanding about systems in China is that using them costs money--paying the power bill at the very least.

Comment: If the system is made in the US, citizens of, e.g. Iran and Syria will not be allowed to use it -- no matter what country the computer is actually located in or owned by.  US export control laws are a condition of the sale of such systems (for instance, even in Saudi Arabia).