# Super Computer cluster service for students

Tags: molecular-dynamics, hpc

I would like to ask whether there is a free of charge supercomputer for students, in my current institution they don't have a supercomputer, I am running MD simulations, I would be grateful for suggestions.

Comment: While I'm not entirely sure this is the right place to ask this, some indication of the country you are in might help.

Comment: Does [this recent question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/32852/20688) and  [this question mentioned in my answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/15884/20688) provide an answer?

Comment: Are there other researchers at your institution doing MD? How do they cope?
Do some research on your institution. Even if they do not have a supercomputer, many institutions have computer labs with reasonable network speeds. Some institutions have the possibility to make use of those over night. It is certainly not the most efficient or elegant solution, but a classroom full of reasonable computers used over night might do the trick for you. Is your application mpi-parallel? What kind of packages are you using? Do you have an estimate of how many wall hours you might need on a known setup?

Comment: How big is your problem?

Comment: What country do you and your students have citizenship in? Free clusters for sometimes provided by governments, but usually only for their citizens.